# Full image full screen in nextjs tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I would like to ask you a question.

how to make the image full screen and responsive.
For example, I made it on a 10 inch screen, then I tried it on a 13 inch screen and it was responsive according to the device used.

Thank you.

example: https://h2l5nk.csb.app/

my code =

```
import BackgroundQuickTips from "@images/background/quick-tips-page.svg";

<BackgroundQuickTips className="bg-blue-50 bg-cover w-full h-screen" />
```